# How to generate java client using Apollo GraphQL?

Tags: apollo-client

I have tried steps mentioned in the official doc but it showing Error: **Unsupported target: java**

In CLI help, java is not listed as a target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Server setup**

Spring Boot with GraphQL Server: https://www.graphql-java.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-spring-boot/

Full working GraphQL server code exist on GitHub: https://github.com/graphql-java/tutorials/tree/master/book-details

**Client**

Generate GraphQL Query Code from schema

- Create Java Project with the following build.gradle

> ```
> buildscript {
>     repositories {
>         jcenter()
>     }
>     dependencies {
>         classpath 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-gradle-plugin:0.5.0'
>     }
> }
>
> plugins {
>     id 'java'
> }
>
> apply plugin: 'com.apollographql.android'
>
> group = 'com.graphql-java.tutorial'
> version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
> sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
>
> repositories {
>     jcenter()
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     compile group: 'com.apollographql.apollo', name: 'apollo-runtime', version: '0.5.0'
> }
> ```

- Create GraphQL Query file (BookById.graphQL), same namedjava file will be generated (Reference: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/essentials/get-started.html#creating-graphql-file)
- Put BookById.graphQL file in main.graphql package with expected package hierarchy
  Example: main/graphql/com/apollographql/apollo/sample/BookById.graphql;
- Download schema.jsonfromthe GraphQL server endpoint
  Go to CLI, run below command, it will generate schema.json

  > apollo service:download --endpoint=http://localhost:8080/graphql
- Put *schema.json* in *main/graphql*
- Run Gradle build task it will generate Client Query Code in **Build/generated/source/apollo** with same package structure as of *BookById.graphql*

  BookByIdQuery.java

**References:**

Server GraphQL-Java : https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/master/

Apollo Client: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/essentials/get-started.html

Spring Boot with GraphQL Query Example | Tech Primers: https://youtu.be/zX2I7-aIldE

"Building a data API with GraphQL and Spring" - API Craft Singapore:  https://youtu.be/GmR2uIDZEyM

Comment: What should the BookById.graphQL contain? 
I tried with 
`query bookById($id: ID!) {
    book(id: $id) {
        id
        name
        pageCount
        author {
            lastName
        }
    }
}
`

I get: 
`
bookquery.graphql (2:4)
  Can't query `book` on type `Query`
  ----------------------------------------------------
  [1]:query bookById($id: ID!) {
  [2]:    book(id: $id) {
  [3]:        id
  ----------------------------------------------------
`

Answer (score -1):

With code-first approach, an elegant solution for Java GraphQL clients is: [vertx-graphql-client](https://github.com/graphqly/vertx-graphql-client)